# Can't see Docker daemon when invoking script through NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, docker, child-process

I'm using NodeJS and `child_process` to kick off a deploy script. In the deploy script is a few calls to Docker. The script runs successfully, but the problem is that when the script gets invoked through NodeJS, it says that it "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon." When I invoke the script manually, though, it's fine.

The relevant NodeJS script:

```
var cp = require('child_process');

cp.exec('deploy.sh', {shell: '/bin/bash', cwd: '/deploy', uid: userid.uid('ubuntu'), gid: userid.gid('ubuntu')}, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log("Output: " + stdout);
});
```

Any idea why this is, and how to fix it? I've checked the output and `whoami` returns the proper user.

**Edit**: I tried running the script in Ruby:

```
userdata = Etc.getpwnam('ubuntu')
stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3("./deploy.sh", :chdir=>"/deploy", :uid => userdata.uid, :gid => userdata.gid)
```

And I get the same result - that the Docker daemon isn't running. In `/var/run/`:

```
drwx------  4 root       root         80 Jan 20 21:32 docker/
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root          5 Jan 20 22:57 docker.pid
srw-rw----  1 root       docker        0 Jan 20 22:57 docker.sock=
```

Overall, this whole thing makes me think that it's a permissions issue.

Comment: Is docker running locally? How are you connecting to the daemon (tcp or socket-connection)? If the daemon is protected by TLS, it's possible that NodeJS is not using the environment variables that are used for configuring the connection; https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#environment-variables. In that case, either use a configuration-file, or explicitly pass the right options as flag

Comment: @thaJeztah: Yes, Docker is running locally. But you got me thinking. I looked in /var/run, and found: `root       docker        0 Jan 20 22:57 docker.sock`. So `docker.sock` is owned by root in the docker group. Following that, if I change `gid` to use `docker` instead of `ubuntu`, Docker loads - but my script fails out if I do that. I've tried setting `export DOCKER_HOST="unix:///var/run/docker.sock"` in a number of places, including the NodeJS exec above, and that also has no effect.

Comment: Can you try running `env` in the child process to confirm it has the correct environment variables? Able to post the `deploy.sh` script as well? Might be worth just trying to run `docker ps` or something simple to start eliminating possible suspects.

Comment: @AndyShinn: `env` shows very little - `PWD`, `_`, and `DOCKER_HOST` if I specify it. `deploy.sh` kicks off a build script that does things such as `docker build -t api .` and `docker tag -f api $docker_repo/api`. If I put `docker ps` in the script, it gives me the same "Cannot connect" error. If I set `uid` and `gid` to 'root', `docker ps` gives an output - but then the rest of the script errors out because of other permissions.

Comment: All options to connect to the daemon can also be provided as flags; the environment variables are just for convenience. For example `docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock version`. Other options, such as `--tlscert` can also be provided. Note that these are "top level" options, so should go **before** the subcommand that's run (in this example `info`)

Comment: @thaJeztah: I tried invoking it as `export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock` `docker -H $DOCKER_HOST ps -a`, and that doesn't work either. Given that the `docker.sock` is owned by root and in the docker group, I'm starting to think this is an issue in how NodeJS's `child_process.exec` works.

Comment: I've added some detail to the question. Running in Ruby shows the same result.

Comment: Have you been always testing with `export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock docker <cmd>`? That isn't a proper usage of `export`, you are passing `docker -H $DOCKER_HOST ps -a` as arguments to `export`. You should use the `child_process` `env` object to pass the environment variable. I'd still like to see some examples of just regular `docker` commands without `deploy.sh`. I feel like it is probably something simple being missed.

Comment: I also tried it through `child_process`' `env`, but yeah, that did nothing. I rewrote the script in Ruby (it was short) and it works fine with the same parameters, i.e. same userid and groupid. I think this is just something in how NodeJS spawns child processes.

Answer (score 0):

Docker need tty input. But "child_process" library is working bad when tty mode.
I have tried for docker, with microsoft node-pty library https://github.com/microsoft/node-pty

> node-pty library is a pseudo tty library.
> And this is worked me.

```
const pty = require("node-pty");
let deploy = pty.spawn('/path/to/deploy.sh',[/*List of arguments*/] )
deploy.on('data', (e)=>console.log(e));
deploy.write("1+2");
```